# Unable to create Channel from class class io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel while starting master in Apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, netty

This is what i was getting when trying to start the master using `runMaster.sh` in `spark`:

> 07:21:23.613 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.ThreadLocalRandom - -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier: 0xb1b69a9d4b332f61 (took 0 ms)
>   Exception in thread "main" io.netty.channel.ChannelException: Unable to create Channel from class class io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel
>           at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$BootstrapChannelFactory.newChannel(AbstractBootstrap.java:457)
>           at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:308)
>           at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.doBind(AbstractBootstrap.java:272)
>           at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.bind(AbstractBootstrap.java:268)
>           at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportServer.init(TransportServer.java:129)
>           at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportServer.(TransportServer.java:74)
>           at org.apache.spark.network.TransportContext.createServer(TransportContext.java:114)
>           at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.startServer(NettyRpcEnv.scala:118)
>           at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnvFactory$$anonfun$4.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:446)
>           at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnvFactory$$anonfun$4.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:445)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:2213)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:2204)
>           at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnvFactory.create(NettyRpcEnv.scala:450)
>           at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:56)
>           at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:43)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master$.startRpcEnvAndEndpoint(Master.scala:1046)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master$.main(Master.scala:1030)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master.main(Master.scala)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.newAtomicIntegerFieldUpdater(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater;
>           at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:95)
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.(AbstractChannel.java:370)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.(AbstractNioChannel.java:172)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel$NioMessageUnsafe.(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:48)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel$NioMessageUnsafe.(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:48)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel.newUnsafe(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:45)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel.newUnsafe(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:34)
>           at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.(AbstractChannel.java:80)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel.(AbstractNioChannel.java:82)
>           at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel.(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:40)
>           at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.(NioServerSocketChannel.java:84)
>           at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.(NioServerSocketChannel.java:70)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
>           at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$BootstrapChannelFactory.newChannel(AbstractBootstrap.java:455)
>           ... 18 more

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have different versions of netty artifacts on the class path. Ensure you use the same version for all of these.

Comment: But all the jars came inbuilt with the spark*.tar. So shouldn't a netty*.jar be picked up automatically?

Comment: maybe you also have other netty versions on your class path ? Inspect it carefully.